# Pygame black screen

Tags: pygame

I seem to have Pygame installed - but when I run any Pygame code I cannot get past the black Pygame screen. I sometimes get an error message that some .PNG fie cannot be found. It is quite frustrating as it was difficult enough to get past the module not recognized hurdle. I have tried adjusting pop up settings and looking through directories to see if images are there but can't find a really straightforward solution. On the verge of giving up.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/install/)

Comment: Without any code posted by you, nobody can say what's wrong with your code...

Comment: Does `import pygame; pygame.init()` work?

Answer (score 1):

The black pygame screen could be a plethera of coding problems like a lack of

```
pygame.display.update ()
```

or indentation problems or just a general coding issue. The png error your coming up with is the program your trying to run requires a png in the same location as it(easiest way is to put the png in a folder with your .py program) these pngs should come with the game and if not then you can rename a existing png to take its place.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some magical links to help you:

[www.pygame.org/](http://www.pygame.org/)

[inventwithpython.com/pygame/](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/)

[pygametutorials.wikidot.com/](http://pygametutorials.wikidot.com/)

I know, I also hate link-only answers. But this is a type of question that needs one.